# How to have log tick marks face inward?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get these tickmarks for the y-axis to go inward. I have these lines after the `plt.plot()` lines:

```css
plt.tick_params(axis='x', direction='in')
plt.tick_params(axis="y", direction="in")
plt.yscale("log")
```

The ticks are inward for the x-axis but not fully so for the y-axis. The log ticks don't seem to be inward. I've tried having the `plt.yscale("log")` line before and after the `.tick_params` lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the minor ticks in the `tick_params` function using the `which=` argument shown in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params.html).

```
plt.tick_params(axis="y", which="both", direction="in")
```